# Angular 2 QuickStart Tutorial - npm command error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Iam new in angular2,and i following 'QuickStart'(https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) tutorial.When i try to run the project using `npm start` command the below error content is produce:

```
/home/noufal/Learn/angularjs2/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.sorting.js:36
    observableProto = Observable.prototype,
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at /home/noufal/Learn/angularjs2/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.sorting.js:36:33
    at Object.factory.call.Observable (/home/noufal/Learn/angularjs2/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.sorting.js:29:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/noufal/Learn/angularjs2/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.sorting.js:33:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-65-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/noufal/Learn/angularjs2/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: the order in which you imported js files in your index.html matters. try importing all modules correctly.